# How to change <th> tooltip on Laravel DataTables

Tags: laravel, tooltip, yajra-datatable

I use Yajra DataTables for Laravel and pass my column properties like this:

```
        [
            'name' => 'remind_me',
            'title' => '<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>',
            'data' => 'remind_me',
        ]
```

The resulting `<th>` shows the icon as required, but on hovering a tooltip pops up, showing the title in raw html.

I want this tooltip to show some text, like 'remind me'. I'm not sure where this tooltip gets generated, but hoped it'd be as easy as adding another attribute like `'tooltip' => 'remind me'`. However I can't find this option on https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns

So my question is: how can I change the text on the autogenerated  tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just saw it at the source code of Yajra Datatables, use:

"titleAttr"

Example:

```
       [
            'name' => 'remind_me',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'titleAttr' => 'Tooltip!'
            'data' => 'remind_me',
        ]
```